# Lock Dock To 1 Screen

Tags: dock

I'm using 2 screens and I keep hitting the bottom of the second screen and the dock jumps to that screen. The problem is it doesn't jump back if you do the same on the original screen.

Is there anyway to stop it from moving? I will never want it on anything other than the original screen, it just freaks me out.

Comment: The only *absolute* fix I know of is to switch off System prefs > Mission Control > Display have separate spaces.

Comment: @Tetsujin this doesn't fix the problem. I have the same issue and it's very annoying, didn't find a solution so far....

Comment: It should do - I've had the dock on only one screen since Spaces was invented, by not using that setting.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I've found for this issue is to change the dock position from Bottom to Left/Right (*System Preferences* > *Dock & Menu Bar*). Once you've done that the dock will only appear on your main display (as set in *System Preferences* > *Displays* > *Display Settings...*).

As I say, it's more of a workaround than a solution: I haven't found a solution that still allows you to position the dock at the bottom of the screen.